# How to scroll down, but at a specific location, until there is no more href to scrape?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, scroll

I'm facing a problem,

I want to scrape all the watches's link here : https://www.omegawatches.com/fr-fr/watchfinder

But we need to scroll down to make visible all the link (1400 in total), but not at the very bottom because it will not scroll.

I tried this :

```
initial_value = 0

next_value = 300

while next_value<300000:

    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(initial_value,next_value);")

    time.sleep(0.5)

    initial_value=next_value
    n = n + 300


url2 = driver.current_url
results = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

all_title = soup.find_all('a', class_ = 'ow-prod__img')
data_titles = []
for title in all_title:
    try:
        product_link = title['href']
        data_titles.append(product_link)
    except:
        pass

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'links' : data_titles
    })

data.to_csv("testlink4.csv", sep=';', index=False)
```

But it doesn't seems to work.

How could I make a loop who scrape all the href for the watches until the very end ?

Here's one example for the html to the href needed :

[htmlhref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvAsC.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, if it could help someone later :

```
PATH = "driver\chromedriver.exe"
#path to modify if needed

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 


options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument('enable-logging')
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=PATH)


driver.get('https://www.omegawatches.com/fr-fr/watchfinder')


for i in range(730):

    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 250)")
    time.sleep(1)

url2 = driver.current_url
results = requests.get(url2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

all_title = soup.find_all('a', class_ = 'ow-prod__img')
data_titles = []
for title in all_title:
    try:
        product_link = title['href']
        data_titles.append(product_link)
    except:
        pass

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'links' : data_titles
    })

data.to_csv("testlink4.csv", sep=';', index=False)
```